# Почему компилятор молчит, когда массиву присваивается массив в Си, хотя данные не копируются?

Tags: c, массивы

```
bool mas1[1] = {true};
bool mas2[1] = {false};
mas1=mas2; // что тут произошло?
```

Присваивание массивов не приводит к копированию данных членов из правого выражения в левое. А что происходит, почему, и почему компилятор не ругается (GCC)?

Comment: Обычно это не глубокая копия. Присваивается значение переменной - т.е. указатель

Comment: А что у вас за компилятор? `gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` говорит -- *`error: assignment to expression with array type`*

Comment: https://ideone.com/bXti8n

Comment: Это не должно компилироваться. Нужен полный минимальный воспроизводимый пример (начиная с `include` и далее) + версия компилятора + опции компиляции.